# C++ Refactoring a method that takes either an int or string argument

Tags: c++, refactoring

I have been working on creating a program to store a collection of students. I realized that I was essentially using the same copy/paste code to create basically the same methods for my various class containers. I decided to refactor the code and have reworked most of it. The problem I am currently facing is using my search method. With some of my collections, the search method took and returned an integer ID (Student Number for example), while other collections took and returned string ID's (Course Code for example). I have been stuck trying to figure out how to create a single method that can handle both of these cases.

I essentially want the code I have below, but I want it to take and return the type that is passed into it (either int or string). Note that getID() is just a method that was used to return the student ID from the student class or the course code from the course class.

```
template <typename S>
S * findID([string or int] ID){
    for (typename vector<S*>::collectionsIter element = collection.begin() ; element != collection.end(); ++element)
        if((*element)->getID() == ID) return *element;
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: First, you don't need a separate function -- `std::find_if` with a predicate / functor / lambda is what you could use.

Answer (score 0):

You may use template, something like:

```
template <typename Collection, typename ID>
auto* find_by_id(Collection& collection, const ID& id)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(collection), std::end(collection),
                        [&](const auto* e) { return e->getID() == id; })
    if (it == std::end(collection)) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    return *it;
}
```